# SELECT только увеличивающиеся значения MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Не могу подобрать запрос со сравнением ячейки по предыдущей строке. что то типа

```
SELECT * FROM `tab` WHERE col>col(предыдущей строки) ORDER BY id limit 99999
```

`MySQL` - Версия сервера: `10.4.11-MariaDB`.

У меня есть хронология изменения цены с параметрами этого изменения, мне нужны только те строки, в результате которых цена выросла.

Comment: Что вы пытаетесь этим запросом сделать?

Comment: А версия MySQL - она какая? И что такое "предыдущая строка"?

Comment: MySQL - Версия сервера: 10.4.11-MariaDB.  У меня есть хронологоия изменения цены с параметрами этого изменения, мне нужны только те строки, в результате которых цена выросла

Comment: Если вам нужны все строки которые больше предыдущей то вам хватит обычного `where col > число`. Скажем у вас начинается отсчет с 4х и вам надо достать строки которые больше предыдущей, то и получается что нужны все строки которые больше 4

Comment: "число" в каждой строке свое это не статический параметр

Comment: Дайте скрин с базы со строками, не совсем понятно что вам нужно

Comment: таблица http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/88888888.1584451264.jpg

Comment: динамика цены(price) по времени, нужно оставить только те строки после которых цена например выросла

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.id AS id1,t2.id AS id2,
t1.price AS price1,t2.price AS price2,
t2.price - t1.price AS diff
FROM tab AS t1,tab AS t2
WHERE t1.id+1=t2.id AND (t2.price - t1.price)>0
ORDER BY t1.id
```

Исходная таблица.

[image]

Результат запроса.

[image]

Берем 2 раза одну таблицу, но со смещением в одну строку `t1.id+1=t2.id`, у нас получается в одной строчке текущая и следующая строчки, разница `price` заносится в колонку `diff`.

Но запрос будет работать только при условии, если все значения по колонке id последовательные, то есть 1,2,3,4 и так далее.

Comment: Спасибо! Механику понял